# texture drawing from bottom of screen

Tags: c++, opengl

Im a little confused on why.

for some reason with my draw function my textures are drawing from the bottom up.

So 0 is the bottom have i done something wrong with my code.
The width is drawing from left to right like normal.

```
void Texture::draw(float x, float y)
{
    // OpenGL calls
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    GLfloat vertices_position[] = {
        x, y,
        x + m_width, y,
        x + m_width, y + m_height,
        x, y + m_height,
    };
    GLfloat texture_coord[] = {
        1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
        1.0f, 0.0f,// bottom right
        0.0f, 0.0f,// bottom left
        0.0f, 1.0f,// top left 
    };

    // snap to pixel
    int shiftX = (int)(x + 0.5f);
    int shiftY = (int)(y + 0.5f);


    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices_position);

    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texture_coord);

    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    //glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    float color[4] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    glColor4fv(color);

    glPushMatrix();
    //glTranslatef(m_width, 1.0f, 0);
    //glRotatef(90, 0.0f, 0, 1);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_object);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

    glPopMatrix();

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

edit:
This fixed the rotation of my image

```
GLfloat vertices_position[] = {
    x + m_width, y,
    x + m_width, y + m_height,
    x, y + m_height,
    x, y
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [OpenGL 4.6 API core profile specification; 8.5. TEXTURE IMAGE SPECIFICATION; page 214](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)

> An element *(i, j, k)* of the texture image is called a texel (for a two-dimensional texture or one-dimensional array texture, *k* is irrelevant; for a one-dimensional texture, *j* and *k* are both irrelevant). The texture value used in texturing a fragment is determined by sampling the texture in a shader, but may not correspond to any actual texel. See figure 8.3.
>
> [image: textureimage]
>
> Figure 8.3. A texture image and the coordinates used to access it. This is a twodimensional texture with width 8 and height 4. A one-dimensional texture would consist of a single horizontal strip. α and β, values used in blending adjacent texels to obtain a texture value are also shown.

See the order of the primitives for the primitive type `GL_QUAD`:

[image: quad]

This means that your code results in the following:

```
GLfloat vertices_position[] = {
    x, y,
    x + m_width, y,
    x + m_width, y + m_height,
    x, y + m_height,
};
GLfloat texture_coord[] = {
    1.0f, 1.0f, 
    1.0f, 0.0f
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
};
```

```
            x, y           x + m_width, y              1.0f, 1.0f           1.0f, 0.0f
                o------->o                                        o------->o              
                         |                                                 |
                         |                                                 |
                         v                                                 v
                o<-------o                                        o<-------o 
x, y + m_height           x + m_width, y + m_height    0.0f, 1.0f            0.0f, 0.0f
```

To achieve what you want you either have to change the texture coordinates:

```
GLfloat texture_coord[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f, 
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f 
};
```

```
            x, y           x + m_width, y              0.0f, 1.0f           1.0f, 1.0f
                o------->o                                        o------->o         
                         |                                                 |
                         |                                                 |
                         v                                                 v
                o<-------o                                        o<-------o 
x, y + m_height           x + m_width, y + m_height    0.0f, 0.0f            1.0f, 0.0f
```

Or the vertex coordinates:

```
GLfloat vertices_position[] = {
    x + m_width, y,
    x + m_width, y + m_height,
    x, y + m_height,
    x, y
};
```

```
            x, y          x + m_width, y               0.0f, 1.0f           1.0, 1.0
                o        o                                        o        o
                ^        |                                        ^        |
                |        |                                        |        |
                |        v                                        |        v
                o<-------o                                        o<-------o 
x, y + m_height           x + m_width, y + m_height    0.0f, 0.0f           1.0f, 0.0f
```

---

Extension of the answer, regarding to the comment below:

If you want to encode the texture coordinates in a singel array (*x, y, z, u, v*)

```
GLfloat vertex_attributes[] = {
    x,           y,            z,  0.0f,  1.0f,
    x + m_width, y,            z,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    x + m_width, y + m_height, z,  1.0f,  0.0f,
    x,           y + m_height, z,  0.0f,  0.0f
};
```

then you have to set the *stride*  paramter in [`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml) and [`glTexCoordPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoordPointer.xml)

```
GLsizei stride = 5 * sizeof(GLfloat); // 5 because of x, y, z, u, v

GLfloat *vertex_coordinates  = vertex_attributes;
GLfloat *texture_coordiantes = vertex_attributes; + 3 // 3 because of x, y, z

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, stride, vertex_coordinates);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, stride, texture_coordiantes);
```

---

2nd Extension of the answer, regarding to the comment below:

In the [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) the texture coordinates are transformed by the texture matrix. If the v-cooridnate should be flipped, then the y-axis of the texture matrix has to be inverted (See [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml)):

```
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glLoadIdentity();
glScalef(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Note, do not forget to proper set the matrix mode before 'glOrtho' (`glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);`).

Comment: That is some good info on applying textures. how would i go about drawing from one `GLfloat` array like `// X  Y  Z  U  V`

Comment: wow thankyou, the last thing i wanted to know, was there away to make opengl start to render from the top left, not bottom left?

Answer (score 0):

No, you haven't done anything wrong. OpenGL's coordinate system is Y-up, so 0 is at the bottom.

You can fix this by changing your texture coordinates to flip their Y coordinates. Like this:

```
GLfloat texture_coord[] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, // top right
    1.0f, 1.0f,// bottom right
    0.0f, 1.0f,// bottom left
    0.0f, 0.0f,// top left 
};
```

Alternatively, if your entire model is flipped vertically, you can flip your vertices like this:

```
GLfloat vertices_position[] = {
    x, y + m_height,
    x + m_width, y + m_height,
    x + m_width, y,
    x, y,
};
```

Comment: Thats just fliping my image making it mirrored, i think the main problem is with vertices_position

Comment: Yes, you could also flip the vertices while keeping the texture coordinates the same. It all depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: iwas asking why 0 = the bottom of the screen, in my draw function i would expect y to start from the top of the screen so i was asking how to make it start from the top of screen not bottom.